GCP Postgres Cloud SQL Admin API CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT server roles
Cloud SQL Admin API Method: users.insert.
I'm trying to create a user for GCP CloudSQL Postgres that can connect via IAM.
User creation is successful, and the connection itself is working just fine.
However I have problems in setting the server roles on creation.
No matter what role I set in the request, I always get only 2:

cloudsqliamserviceaccount
my-sa@my-proj.iam

It looks like these roles are ignored when the user type is CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT.
I tried to leave the user creation as is and update it later with proper roles, however I get an:
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Invalid request: User of a different type already exists.",
      "reason": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid request: User of a different type already exists."
}

My bigger goal is to grant access to a db via REST, without making a connection & executing a SQL statement.
Or manual intervention, of course.

Please include specifics as to how you're making the method call (via API Explorer? gcloud? code?). I'm unfamiliar with the method but the error suggests that your instance already contains the name but with a different SqlUserType. Perhaps try updating the user name to the desired type?

Via code, GCP java libraries. I've checked the payload, looks ok.
It's important to say that the creation request is completed successfully, it's just that the server roles are ignored.
For the update and the SqlUserType, I've checked the request, and it's set and correct. I think something else is going on...

Can you explain (using code rather than words) the issue? Something towards a minimal repro. You're getting a 400 which contradicts that the request completed successfully. I think you mean that there's partial success: the user is created but the type isn't correctly assigned. You may be correct that something else is going on but it's difficult to infer from your question.

User CREATION:
POST 'https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/users'  
{"instance":"my-instance","name":"my-sa@my-project.iam","passwordPolicy":{"enablePasswordVerification":false},"project":"my-project","sqlserverUserDetails":{"disabled":false,"serverRoles":["pg_read_all_data","pg_write_all_data"]},"type":"CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"}

Response: OK.
Server roles ignored. It was created only with the 2 from above.

User UPDATE:
PUT https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/users?name=my-sa@my-project.iam
{"etag":"XXX","host":"","instance":"my-instance","kind":"sql#user","name":"my-sa@my-project.iam","password":"a","project":"my-project","sqlserverUserDetails":{"disabled":false,"serverRoles":["pg_read_all_data","pg_write_all_data"]},"type":"CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Invalid request: User of a different type already exists.

This is from a GET operation:
{
  "kind": "sql#user",
  "etag": "xxx",
  "name": "my-sa@my-project.iam",
  "host": "",
  "instance": "my-instance",
  "project": "my-project",
  "type": "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
}

0 roles.

It's curious that the type of serverRoles is SqlServerUserDetails and is described "Represents a Sql Server user on the Cloud SQL instance". Could it be that this type only applies to (Microsoft) SQL Server?

Hm could be SQL Server specific.
Funnily enough, when I do create a user of the type "built in" I automatically get all these roles: pg_database_owner, pg_monitor, pg_read_all_settings, pg_read_all_stats, pg_stat_scan_tables, pg_signal_backend, pg_checkpoint, cloudsqlsuperuser, my-user.
Widely inconsistent behavior...

It's unclear at best!
